# PHP Web-Application auto refresh Observer Pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, autoload, notify

I am programming web applications for a while now and over the time they became more sophisticated, but sometimes I am not sure if the ways I go are common. Now I am diving into design pattern and thinking about ways to dynamically refresh the contents of the page if the data has changed.

Typically this would be the observer pattern. Now my question. What are the professional ways to automatically load the new data in an open web application?
It would work with javascript and a refresh of the page, sure. But what if javascript is not available?

The observable should notify the observers and force them to update it's data. I would really appreciate a conversation about this topic to get some ideas for future projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For web applications usually used WebSocket. 
PHP only runs on the server once per session you can send the command to subscribers via WebSocket and on client browser javascript can react on it and for example, send the request with another query to your script.

Comment: Thought so, I suppose there is no way without javascript?

Comment: Yes, while browsers use it)